# unable to install angular cli latest

Tags: angular-cli

i am unable to install angular cli. i have uninstalled previous version using npm uninstall -g @angular/cli then i clean cache using npm clean cache --force then i tried npm install -g @angular/cli. i get error as i image everytime.

I have disabled firewall and antivirus to aviod any blockage but nothing worked.

I tried refering similar questions but nothing helped me

[image: Error]

Comment: You tried to run this as admin/root, like the message says?

Comment: i just updated my node version and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Just updated my node version and it worked